# Bower installation on RHE

Tags: node.js, redhat, bower

I'm running into issues getting bower to run properly on RHE. It will run and install packages as root, which requires a permission fix to then work with the new files. Running as a normal user results in completely blank output.

- node v0.10.26
- npm 1.4.3
- bower 1.3.2

This is all new territory for me so any help is appreciated.

Comment: this issue doesn't seem related to any of the packages, its permissions problem i have no experience with RedHat, but doesn't it have `sudo` something like `sudo bower install jquery` ?

Comment: Yes it does, however Bower yells at me to run it as a normal user: "Since bower is a user command, there is no need to execute it with superuser permissions.
If you're having permission errors when using bower without sudo, please spend a few minutes learning more about how your system should work and make any necessary repairs."